# Derivative of Fermi-Dirac Distribution Function to Variable E

Tags: fortran, distribution

I wrote a Fortran code to compute the derivative of Fermi-Dirac distribution function to variable E. The Fermi-Dirac distribution function itself is written below.

$$f_{(E)} =\frac{1}{e^{\frac{E-E_f}{k_BT}}+1}$$

where, $$E$$ and $$T$$ are variables; $$E_f$$ and $$k_B$$ are constant

The derivative of this function to variable is written below.

$$\frac{\partial f_{(E)}}{\partial E} =\frac{1}{k_BT}\frac{e^{\frac{E-E_f}{k_BT}}}{(e^{\frac{E-E_f}{k_BT}}+1)^2}$$

I suppose this derivative function should act as a delta function $$\delta (E-E_F)$$, when $$T$$ is zero.

However, I obtain 'NAN' sign after I ran my Fortran code to compute this derivative function. Here are the results after I ran my code.

```
t=0.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=-0.5                      NaN
t=0.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=0.5                      NaN
t=0.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=1.0                      NaN
t=0.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=5.0                      NaN
t=5.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=0.1   0.000000000000000E+000
t=5.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=-0.5   0.000000000000000E+000
t=5.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=0.5  -3.621485258019960E+021
t=5.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=1.0                      NaN
t=5.0d0 ef = 0.5 e=5.0                      NaN
```

Here are my code.

```
PROGRAM TEST
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION :: e, ef, t,df

t = 0.0d0
ef = 5.0d-1

e = 1.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=0.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=0.1 ', df

e = -5.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=0.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=-0.5 ', df

e = 5.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=0.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=0.5 ', df

e = 1.0d0
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=0.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=1.0 ', df

e = 5.0d0
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=0.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=5.0 ', df

t = 5.0d0

e = 1.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=5.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=0.1 ', df

e = -5.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=5.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=-0.5 ', df

e = 5.0d-1
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=5.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=0.5 ', df

e = 1.0d0
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=5.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=1.0 ', df

e = 5.0d0
CALL FE(e,ef,t,df)
WRITE (UNIT=*, FMT=*) 't=5.0d0 ', 'ef = 0.5 ', 'e=5.0 ', df

STOP

END PROGRAM TEST

SUBROUTINE FE(e,ef,t,df)
IMPLICIT NONE
DOUBLE PRECISION :: e, ef, kb, t,df

kb = 1.380649d-23

df = 0.0d0

df = 1.0d0 / kb / t * EXP(1.0d0 / kb / t * (e - ef))
df = df / (EXP(1.0d0 / kb / t * (e - ef)) + 1.0d0) ** 2
df = df * -1.0d0

RETURN
END SUBROUTINE FE
```

Would anyone please give me some suggestions on how to sort out the problem? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I could say there are two thing wrong with just eye viewing the code

1. There is no provision to handle T=0 in the code. When you pass T=0 you should expect NaN, you divide by 0
2. Looks like units you use are energy in eV, temperature in K. Then your Boltzman constant is completely off.

k<sub>B</sub> = 1/11605 eV/K

Try this code, might work better

```
    SUBROUTINE FE(e, ef, T, df)
    IMPLICIT NONE

    DOUBLE PRECISION :: e, ef, T, df
    DOUBLE PRECISION :: kB, q

    kB = 1.0d0/11605.0d0 ! eV/K

    df = 0.0d0

    if (T .ne. 0.0d0) then ! 0 at T=0 ?
        q = (e - ef)/(kB*T)
        q = EXP( q ) + 1.0d0
        df = (q - 1.0d0) / q / q
        df = df / (kB*T)
    else ! T = 0
        if (e .eq. ef) then
            df = 1.0d0
        endif
    endif

    RETURN
    END SUBROUTINE FE
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Now, I understand how to modify the code under non-zero temperature condition. On other hand, I want to use this derivative function to judge the distributing behavior of electron under different temperature conditions. Under zero temperature condition, this derivative function should act as a Delta function. That means the value of this derivative function should be one, as long as the 'e' variable is same as 'ef'. If not, the value should be zero. Would you please tell me how modify the code to adopt zero temperature condition? Thank you again.

Comment: Something like modified code? Not sure why you're talking about delta-function and value of 1. Integral of delta is one, but delta-function itself is zero except one point where it is more or less infinity.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I think that I understand now.

Comment: @Kieran glad to hear it. If you're happy with the answer, you could accept it and/or bump it

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I am not familiar with this system and did not see the 'Accepted Answer' button next to your answer.

Comment: @Kieran On the left side of the answer, there are: ^ for bump up, number for bumps count, v for bump down and grey tick for acceptance. You could accept question as well as bump it up. F.e. my rules are pretty simple - if answer contribute something to the pool of knowledge at this site, I bump it up. If answer answers the question (and there might be mor than one answer), I accept it.Good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I have already clicked the 'Accepted' and 'Bump up' buttons.